# How to get data from MySQL database and list in the ListView

Tags: android

I've seen numerous questions/tutorials about this, but all of them either use some kind of premade database or work with JSON.

I already created a database and a table with simlpe data that resides on my `MySQL` server, which is running separately as a service on my development machine.

I want to pull the data from that table and list it in the ListView(MainActivity) of my Andoird app when it's launched(onCreate).

At the moment I'm using a premade list of car names.

**Cars table**(in mydb database)

`id`, `name`, `model`, `year`, `vin`, `km`, `price`

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.myfirstproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener  {

    protected String[] cars =  {"BMW", "Audi", "VW", "Ford", "Subaru"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cars);
        ListView carsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listCars);
        carsList.setAdapter(adapter);
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listCars);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you have to transfer the data from your database server to your Android device. The best option is unfortunately JSON and a REST interface to your database.

Comment: You have to create a web service that will return data to you from mysql. You can read [this](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-getting-started-tutorials/8339-connect-android-mysql-database-tutorial.html) tutorial. I tried using the mysql connector but it doesn't work for android.

Comment: Server side, use JSON. Then my suggestion would be to use `AsyncTask` see [example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13197506/1134705). That's how I do it anyway

Comment: @AdrianC.
Interesting tutorial. I would have used it, but the Android code looks like Visual Basic. What gives?

Comment: @zapl 
Is REST a web service?

Comment: Basic4Android, that's why you saw visual basic. And to answer to your second question: REST( REpresentational State Transfer ) defines a set of architectural principles by which you can design Web services. You can have a web service done in grails, or have php script that will return json. Read Asok tutorial for Android part and [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) for the php part that would be your web service.

Comment: @AdrianC.
Isn't there a more short way? I just need to list items and that's it. I want to stick to just Java code. I appreciate the tutorials you've all provided me with, but they seem to be an overkill for my overlysimple app.

Comment: @user1701467, It's really not overkill, just query the DB server-side to an array and then `json_encode()`. The remaining will all be handled with Java.

Comment: @user1701467 Do you mean my answer has a huge amount of material to read? If you were modify my example to fit your needs it would be much more simple. My example includes various data forms on purpose to show how to parse as much as I could think of, I covered images stored in a `MySQL` DB, `Strings` and `Doubles`.

Comment: @Asok
Alright, I'll try to make something of this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I am reluctant to post this answer due to all of the backlash I will get from using deprecated PHP/MySQL functions, but here goes:

Server Side (FYI, look into [MySQLi or PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php), `mysql_connect` is discouraged):

```php
if ($_GET["selectedCompany"] == "true" && $_GET['companyName']) {

    $query = "Your query here";

    mysql_connect($dbserver, $dbusername, $dbpassword) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());  
    $num = mysql_numrows($result);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    $i = 0;
    $rows = array();
    while ($i < $num) {

        $survey_lat['survey_lat'] = mysql_result($result, $i, "survey_lat");
        $survey_lng['survey_lng'] = mysql_result($result, $i, "survey_lng");
        $thumbnail = mysql_result($result, $i, "thumbnail");
        $finalImg['thumbnail'] = base64_encode($thumbnail);
        $sign_type['sign_type'] = mysql_result($result, $i, "sign_type");
        $object_lat['object_lat'] = mysql_result($result, $i, "object_lat");
        $object_lng['object_lng'] = mysql_result($result, $i, "object_lng");

        $finalArray = array_push($rows, array_merge($sign_type, $object_lat, $object_lng, $survey_lat, $survey_lng, $finalImg));

        $i++;
    }

    print json_encode($rows);
    mysql_close();
}
```

Client/Android side `AsyncTask` to retrieve (I modified the answer I gave before to reflect the mysql query and how to parse that JSON data):

```java
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = ""; 

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Your progress dialog message...");
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
                MyAsyncTask.this.cancel(true);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        String url_select = "http://yoururlhere.com/index.php?selectedCompany=true&companyName=examplevalue";

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        try {
            // Set up HTTP post
            // HttpClient is more then less deprecated. Need to change to URLConnection
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            // Read content & Log
            inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            Log.e("UnsupportedEncodingException", e1.toString());
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e2) {
            Log.e("ClientProtocolException", e2.toString());
            e2.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e3) {
            Log.e("IllegalStateException", e3.toString());
            e3.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e4) {
            Log.e("IOException", e4.toString());
            e4.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Convert response to string using String Builder
        try {
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }

            inputStream.close();
            result = sBuilder.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("StringBuilding & BufferedReader", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
    } // protected Void doInBackground(String... params)


    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

        //parse JSON data
        try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            for(int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String signType = jObject.getString("sign_type");
                double object_lat = jObject.getDouble("object_lat");
                double object_lng = jObject.getDouble("object_lng");
                double survey_lat = jObject.getDouble("survey_lat");
                double survey_lng = jObject.getDouble("survey_lng");
                String thumbnailImg = jObject.getString("thumbnail");
                byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode(thumbnailImg, Base64.DEFAULT);
                bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
                bmImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmImg);

            } // End for Loop

            this.progressDialog.dismiss();

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            Log.e("JSONException", "Error: " + e.toString());

        } // catch (JSONException e)


    } // protected void onPostExecute(Void v)

} //class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>
```